# gnuplot impulse color from third column when using polar coordinates

Tags: colors, gnuplot, polar-coordinates

I'm still pretty new to gnuplot but been playing a lot with it lately. I have a data set with angles (degree), times delay and depth, that I find relevant to display in polar coordinates with the color of the impulses depending on the depth. It works fine when I do it using normal x,y coordinates, but when using the polar coordinates, the color get wrong...

Let's say my data is test.txt:

```
15 0.2 60
30 0.1 50
35 0.4 10
60 0.2 70
90 0.3 12
120 0.2 5
```

If I do:

```
set palette defined ( 0 "red", 1 "yellow", 2 "cyan", 3 "blue", 4 "magenta")
set cbrange [0:80]
set xrange [0:180]
plot "test.txt" u 1:2:3 with impulses lw 2 lc palette
```

It's all good!

But if I use the same palette and I do:

```
set polar
set angles degrees
set xrange[0:0.5]
set yrange[-0.5:0.5]
plot "test.txt" u 1:2:3 with impulses lw 2 lc palette
```

I get a nice polar coordinates graph but not with the right color for my impulses...
What's wrong with this? I've seen post explaining how to color impulses which are using "lc variable" or "lc var z", but it did not work with my polar data...
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a bug in an older gnuplot version. I used the following script to have both outputs beside each other for comparison:

```
set palette defined ( 0 "red", 1 "yellow", 2 "cyan", 3 "blue", 4 "magenta")
set cbrange [0:80]

set multiplot layout 1,2

set yrange [0:0.5]
set xrange [0:180]
plot "test.txt" u 1:2:3 with impulses lw 2 lc palette

set polar
set angles degrees
set xrange [-0.5:0.5]
set yrange [0:0.5]
replot

unset multiplot
```

The wrong output with version 4.4.4 is:

[image]

Since version 4.6.0 the colors are correct:

[image]